# Disable Next.js file-system routing for "api" folder

Tags: javascript, express, routes, next.js

I have a custom created API using **Express** in a folder named `api`. Also, I have a **Next.js** app in another folder.

Both my *Express api* and *Next.js app* share a lot of logic.

What I need to do is to bring my `api` folder within **Next.js** app folder, so I can make common internal modules imported easier.

The problem is that `api` is a special folder for **Next.js** such that it applies somehow **file-system routing** upon it, so it clashes with how **Next.js** works if I brought my Express `api` folder.

Is there any way to **disable Next.js *file-system routing*** for `api` folder? (so I can add my own custom Express api folder and route it easily from a ***custom server*** that handles both Express and Next.js).